# How to cast a string column to date having two different types of date formats in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have a dataframe column which is of type string and has dates in it. I want to cast the column from string to date but the column contains two types of date formats.

I tried using the to_date function but it is not working as expected and giving null values after applying function.

Below are the two date formats I am getting in the df col(datatype - string)

[image]

I tried applying the to_date function and below are the results

[image]

[image]

Please let me know how we can solve this issue and get the date column in only one format

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pyspark.sql.functions.coalesce` to return the first non-null result in a list of columns. So the trick here is to parse using multiple formats and take the first non-null one:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ("9/1/2022",),
    ("2022-11-24",),
], ["Alert Release Date"])


x = F.col("Alert Release Date")

df.withColumn("date", F.coalesce(F.to_date(x, "M/d/yyyy"), F.to_date(x, "yyyy-MM-dd"))).show()
```

```
+------------------+----------+
|Alert Release Date|      date|
+------------------+----------+
|          9/1/2022|2022-09-01|
|        2022-11-24|2022-11-24|
+------------------+----------+
```